# How is the conditions in an illegal_bin declaration interpreted?

Tags: system-verilog

How are the conditions in an illegal_bin declaration handled? Or are they valid at all in the first place? It looks to me that the illegal_bin declaration does not consider any condition in the bins coverpoint_range_list

i.e.

```
illegal_bins invalid_1 = {[0:7]} iff (base == 1600 && basediv == 2);
```

is  same as

```
illegal_bins invalid_1 = {[0:7]};
```

The intention of the `illegal_bin` is that whenever base is 1600 and basediv is 2, any value inside [0:7] of the coverpoint expression is not a valid value.

Is there a way to code `illegal_bins` with conditions other than using the `cross` and `binsof ... intersect` way ?

Below is the sample code.

```
class base_cfg;

  // Divider Values
  rand struct {
    rand bit [ 1: 0] BaseDiv1;
    rand bit [ 2: 0] BaseDiv2;
    rand bit         BaseDiv3;
    rand bit         BaseDiv4;
  } s_basediv;

  rand int BaseVal;


  constraint c_BaseX {
    BaseVal inside {1600, 1400, 1200, 1000, 800};
  }

  constraint c_basediv {
    s_basediv.BaseDiv1      inside {[0: 3]};
    s_basediv.BaseDiv2      inside {[0: 7]};
    s_basediv.BaseDiv3      inside {[0: 1]};
    s_basediv.BaseDiv4      inside {[0: 1]};


    if (BaseVal == 1600) { s_basediv.BaseDiv1 inside {[0:3]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400) { s_basediv.BaseDiv1 inside {[0:2]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200) { s_basediv.BaseDiv1 inside {[0:2]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000) { s_basediv.BaseDiv1 inside {[0:2]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800 ) { s_basediv.BaseDiv1 inside {[0:2]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:3]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:1]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:6]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:2]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:6]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:5]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:2]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:4]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:7]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:3]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv2 inside {[0:1]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv3 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[1:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1600 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[1:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1400 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[1:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1200 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[1:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 1000 && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:0]}; }

    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:1]}; }
    if (BaseVal == 800  && s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3) { s_basediv.BaseDiv4 inside {[0:0]}; }

  }


  function void post_randomize();
    $display($psprintf("BaseVal     = %d", BaseVal));
    $display($psprintf("BaseDiv1    = %d", s_basediv.BaseDiv1));
    $display($psprintf("BaseDiv2    = %d", s_basediv.BaseDiv2));
    $display($psprintf("BaseDiv3    = %d", s_basediv.BaseDiv3));
    $display($psprintf("BaseDiv4    = %d", s_basediv.BaseDiv4));
    $display($psprintf("----------------------------------"));
  endfunction: post_randomize

endclass: base_cfg

class base_cov;


  covergroup base_cg (string name, ref base_cfg   p_base_cfg);

    option.per_instance = 1;
    option.name         = name;
    option.comment      = $sformatf("covergroup for covering ccr clocks");

    BaseVal_cp:      coverpoint p_base_cfg.BaseVal {
                       bins valid[]     = { 1600, 1400, 1200, 1000, 800 };
                       bins default_val = default;
                     }


    BaseDiv1_cp:     coverpoint p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1  {
                        bins valid[] = {[0:3]};
                      }  


    BaseDiv2_cp:     coverpoint p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv2 {
                       bins valid_1600_0[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1600_1[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1600_2[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:3]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1600_3[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1400_0[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1400_1[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:6]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1400_2[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:2]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1400_3[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:6]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1200_0[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1200_1[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:5]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1200_2[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:2]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       bins valid_1000_0[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1000_1[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:4]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1000_2[] = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       bins valid_800_0[]  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_800_1[]  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:3]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_800_2[]  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1600_2 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[4:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1600_3 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[2:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1400_1 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[7:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1400_2 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[3:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1400_3 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[7:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_1 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[6:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_2 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[3:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_3 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_1 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[5:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_2 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[2:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_3 = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_800_1  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[4:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       illegal_bins invalid_800_2  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[2:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_800_3  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:7]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);
                     }

    BaseDiv3_cp:     coverpoint p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv3 {
                       bins valid_1600_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1600_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1600_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1600_3[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1400_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1400_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1400_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       bins valid_1200_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1200_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1200_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       bins valid_1000_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1000_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1000_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       bins valid_800_0[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_800_1[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_800_2[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1600_0 = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1400_1 = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_2 = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_2 = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_3 = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_800_2  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       illegal_bins invalid_800_3  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);
                     }

    BaseDiv4_cp:     coverpoint p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv4 {
                       bins valid_1600_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1600_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1600_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1600_3[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1400_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1400_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1400_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1400_3[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1200_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1200_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1200_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1200_3[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_1000_0[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[1:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_1000_1[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_1000_2[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_1000_3[] = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       bins valid_800_0[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       bins valid_800_1[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 1);
                       bins valid_800_2[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);
                       bins valid_800_3[]  = {[0:1]} with ( (item inside {[0:0]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1600_0 = {[0:0]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1600 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1400_3 = {[1:1]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1400 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_0 = {[0:0]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1200_3 = {[1:1]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1200 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_0 = {[0:0]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 0);
                       illegal_bins invalid_1000_3 = {[1:1]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 1000 && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);

                       illegal_bins invalid_800_3  = {[1:1]} iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 3);
                     }
  endgroup: base_cg

  function new (ref base_cfg base_cfg_h);
    base_cg  = new($sformatf("base_cg"), base_cfg_h);
  endfunction: new 

endclass: base_cov

class base_env;
  rand base_cfg m_base_cfg;
  base_cov m_base_cov;

  function new ();
    m_base_cfg = new();
    m_base_cov = new(m_base_cfg);
  endfunction: new 

endclass: base_env

module top;

  base_env env;

  initial begin
    int count;
    env = new();
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
      for (int j=0; j<8; j++) begin
        $display("\n\ncount = %0d, i = %0d, j = %0d", count, i, j);
        $display($psprintf(".................................."));
        if (!env.randomize() with {m_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == i;}) begin
          $error("env.randomize() with {m_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == %0d;}", i);
        end
        #1;
        env.m_base_cov.base_cg.sample();
        #1;
        count ++;
      end
    end
  end

endmodule: top
```

[image: Coverage result in vcs]

Comment: EDA playground URL: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4gtw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition after the `iff` only influences sampling of the `coverpoint`, `cross` or, in your case, `bins` it was added to. It does **not** influence the values of the bin. You need to specify this in your `cross` bins explicitly using separate `illegal_bins`.

Comment: Thanks @TudorTimi .

The below should work right?

    illegal_bins = default for the illegal_bins part?

i.e.

    bins valid_800_2[]  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

    illegal_bins invalid = default;

Comment: `default` catches values that aren't mapped into any other bin. In you case, each value is already part of at least one other "legal" bin, so there will be nothing left to put in the `default`. What you want is best modeled using cross coverage.

Answer (score 2):

The `iff` expression has no effect on bin creation or removal; it only filters sampling. You can get the coverage you are looking for by using a `cross` and moving the `iff` expression inside the `with` clause

Comment: how about making the illegal_bins = default? do you see any problems with that aswell?

bins valid_800_2[]  = {[0:7]} with ( (item inside {[0:1]}) ) iff (p_base_cfg.BaseVal == 800  && p_base_cfg.s_basediv.BaseDiv1 == 2);

    illegal_bins invalid = default;